# How do get returned int value of a list in java?

Tags: java, list

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class ListAction extends Frame implements ItemListener{

    List list;
    Label label;
    public ListAction(){

      // Set frame properties
      setTitle("List with ItemListener Demo");
      setSize(400,400);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
              System.exit(0);
          }
      });
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

      // Create List
      list=new List();

      // Create label
      label=new Label("                                ");

      // Add items
      list.add("Apple");
      list.add("Mango");
      list.add("Guava");
      list.add("Orange");
      list.add("Pineapple");
      list.add("Grapes");



      // Add List
      add(list);

      // Add label
      add(label);

      // Add item listener
      list.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
      label.setText("You selected "+list.getSelectedItem());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    new ListAction();
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to get the size of the list, but I keep getting errors when I try.

Comment: You don't have any methods with a return type that isn't void so I'm not sure where exactly you want to "return" an int.

Comment: What did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: I don't need it for this code, basically what I want is someone to tell me how do I find out the length or size of the list and the number to be a int.

Comment: Like `list.size()`? Also, don't post a bunch of code if it has no bearing on your question.

Comment: When I do 'int listCount = list.size();' I get ListAction.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
     list = new ArrayList<String>();
                ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class ListAction

Comment: If you read the documentation for List:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html

then you will see that getItemCount() gets the number of items

Comment: Thilo and JoeBlade helped me out, I was looking at the wrong doc's I should of been looking at the AWT list as it helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `list.getItemCount()`. It returns the number of items in the awt list.

`list.size()` **[deprecated]** or `list.getSize()` returns the dimension of the list on screen.